# Authorize.net: How does the user specify the default payment method? How am I to guess?

Tags: ruby, authorize.net

When the user [edits their payment methods on the hosted payment profile manage page](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/customer_profiles.html#Using_the_Accept_Customer_Hosted_Form), they are able to enter multiple payment methods and credit cards. There is no way to select a default.

[image]

When I go to get the payment profile right before a charge and leave out the payment profile id to get the default, it gives an error.

https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#customer-profiles-get-customer-payment-profile

> Note: If the payment profile has previously been set as the default payment profile, you can submit this request using customerProfileId as the only parameter. Submitting this request with only the customer profile ID will cause the information for the default payment profile to be returned if a default payment profile has been previously designated. If no payment profile has been designated as the default payment profile, failing to specify a payment profile will result in an error.

```
irb(main):016:0> request = GetCustomerPaymentProfileRequest.new
irb(main):017:0> request.customerProfileId = @subscription.authorizenet.customer_profile_id
=> "1503823608"
irb(main):018:0> response = transaction.get_customer_payment_profile(request)
irb(main):019:0> response.messages.resultCode
=> "Error"
irb(main):020:0> response.messages.messages[0].text
=> "No default payment/shipping profile found."
```

So how do I get the default payment profile id? Yes, I could get *all* the payment profiles, but still, how would I know which one the customer intended to use?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. You are supposed to display another form for the user to select the default. Completely retarded. Makes me want to just violate PCI compliance and just store all the credit cards myself.

https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Get-Accept-Customer-Profile-Page/m-p/59069/highlight/true#M33670

> There is no way for the customer to indicate on the form which profile they would like as the default. However, you can accomplish this by using the API to do a getCustomerPaymentProfileListRequest to retrieve [all of the] payment profiles, and then presenting that list to the customer in a way that the customer can indicate to you which one should be the default. Then, you'd do an updateCustomerPaymentProfileRequest to set the chosen profile as the default.

I ended up just allowing one payment profile. If the payment profile id doesn't exist, then it displays the ADD form. If it does, then it displays the EDIT form. The only disadvantage is it doesn't allow the user to switch between credit card and bank account after they've created the payment profile.

`routes.rb`

```
  resource :payment_profile, only: [:edit] do # Authorize.net customer profile & payment profile
    collection do
      get :anedit
      post :charge
    end 
  end
```

`payment_profiles_controller.rb`

```
class PaymentProfilesController < ApplicationController
  include AuthorizeNet::API
  before_action :set_subscription
  layout false, only: :anedit

  def edit
    unless @subscription.authorizenet
      create_empty_customer_profile
    else
      get_customer_profile # update profile as they may have added a payment profile (or not)
    end
  end

  def anedit
    unless @subscription.authorizenet # in case #edit failed to create a new empty profile
      render plain: "No customer profile available to edit. Please try again later." and return
    end
    @payment_profile_id = @subscription.authorizenet.customer_payment_profile_id
    if Rails.env == 'production'
      if @payment_profile_id
        @action_url = "https://accept.authorize.net/customer/editPayment"
      else
        @action_url = "https://accept.authorize.net/customer/addPayment"
      end
    else
      if @payment_profile_id
        @action_url = "https://test.authorize.net/customer/editPayment"
      else
        @action_url = "https://test.authorize.net/customer/addPayment"
      end
    end

    # show hosted form
    ...
    setting5 = SettingType.new
    setting5.settingName = SettingNameEnum::HostedProfileBillingAddressRequired
    setting5.settingValue = true

    settings = Settings.new([setting1, setting2, setting3, setting4, setting5, setting6])

    request = GetHostedProfilePageRequest.new
    request.customerProfileId = @subscription.authorizenet.customer_profile_id
    request.hostedProfileSettings = settings

    response = transaction.get_hosted_profile_page(request)

    if response.messages.resultCode == MessageTypeEnum::Ok
      # puts "Successfully got Accept Customer page token."
      # puts "  Response code: #{response.messages.messages[0].code}"
      # puts "  Response message: #{response.messages.messages[0].text}"
      # puts "  Token: #{response.token}"
      @token = response.token
    else
      # puts "#{response.messages.messages[0].code}"
      # puts "#{response.messages.messages[0].text}"
      render plain: "Failed to get hosted profile page with customer profile ID #{request.customerProfileId}: #{response.messages.messages[0].code} #{response.messages.messages[0].text}"
      return
    end
  end

  # create authorize.net customer profile
  def create_empty_customer_profile
    # Build the request object
    request = CreateCustomerProfileRequest.new
    # Build the profile object containing the main information about the customer profile
    request.profile = CustomerProfileType.new
    request.profile.merchantCustomerId = @user.id
    request.profile.email = @user.email

    response = transaction.create_customer_profile(request)

    if response != nil
      puts response.messages.resultCode
      if response.messages.resultCode == MessageTypeEnum::Ok
        puts "Successfully created a customer profile with id: #{response.customerProfileId}"
        puts "  Customer Payment Profile Id List:"
        response.customerPaymentProfileIdList.numericString.each do |id|
          puts "    #{id}"
        end
        puts "  Customer Shipping Address Id List:"
        response.customerShippingAddressIdList.numericString.each do |id|
          puts "    #{id}"
        end
        @subscription.create_authorizenet user: @user, customer_profile_id: response.customerProfileId #, customer_payment_profile_id: response.customerPaymentProfileIdList.numericString.first
      else
        puts response.messages.messages[0].code
        puts response.messages.messages[0].text
        flash.now.alert = "Failed to create a new customer profile: #{response.messages.messages[0].code} #{response.messages.messages[0].text}"
        #render :new
      end
    else
      puts "Response is null"
      flash.now.alert = "Failed to create a new customer profile."
    end
  end

  def get_customer_profile
    request = GetCustomerProfileRequest.new
    request.customerProfileId = @subscription.authorizenet.customer_profile_id

    response = transaction.get_customer_profile(request)

    if response.messages.resultCode == MessageTypeEnum::Ok
      puts "Successfully retrieved customer profile of customer ID #{request.customerProfileId}."
      response.profile.paymentProfiles.each do |paymentProfile|
        puts "  Payment Profile ID #{paymentProfile.customerPaymentProfileId}" 
        puts "  Payment Details:"
        if paymentProfile.billTo != nil
          puts "    Last Name: #{paymentProfile.billTo.lastName}"
          puts "    Address: #{paymentProfile.billTo.address}"    
        end
      end
      if response.subscriptionIds != nil && response.subscriptionIds.subscriptionId != nil
        puts "  List of subscriptions: "
        response.subscriptionIds.subscriptionId.each do |subscriptionId|
          puts "    #{subscriptionId}"
        end
      end
      # now update the payment profile id
      @subscription.authorizenet.update customer_payment_profile_id: response.profile.paymentProfiles.first&.customerPaymentProfileId
    else
      puts response.messages.messages[0].text
      flash.alert = "Failed to get profile of customer ID #{request.customerProfileId}."
    end 
    return response
  end
```

And the views

`edit.haml`

```
-content_for :head do
  %meta(name="turbolinks-cache-control" content="no-preview")
%iframe{src: anedit_user_subscription_payment_profile_path(@user), width: '100%', height: '900px', frameborder: 0}
```

`anedit.haml`

```
%form#authorizenetform{:action => @action_url, :method => "post"}
  %input{:type => "hidden", :name => "token", :value => @token}/
  -if @payment_profile_id
    %input{:type => "hidden", :name => "paymentProfileId", :value => @payment_profile_id}/ 
  %input{:type => "submit", :value => "Update Payment"}/
-# Separate iframe document without layout. No access to JQuery.
:javascript
  document.getElementById('authorizenetform').submit();
```